# Disable evil-mode in calendar

Tags: init-file, evil, calendar

On the following setup:

- GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (i586-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.14.5) of 2015-03-07 on binet, modified by Debian
- Evil version 1.1.6

If I enter `M-x calendar`, I find that several of the keybindings listed in the manual don't work. For example, instead of [scrolling forward by 3 months](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Scroll-Calendar.html#Scroll-Calendar), `C-v` instead enters Visual Block Mode.

Without uninstalling evil-mode, by which means can I prevent the default keybindings being intercepted, so that they will function as described in the Emacs manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(evil-set-initial-state 'calendar-mode 'emacs)` should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before asking, but I now see that it apparently needs to come after e.g. `(require 'evil) (evil-mode t)` .

Comment: Right. That's because `evil-set-initial-state` is defined in `evil-core.el`